# getting a variable in php from html without form

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to get a variable in to php from html without using form. 
so i don't have method option post,get etc. as i have attached the code, i want value of the variable 'buy1' in php, i tried id instead of name, but didn't work , because how to access in php file without using get or post and action attribute? i am really struggling here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myPlaylist = [
    {
        mp3:'thumb/audio/1.mp3',
        //oga:'thumb/audio/1.ogg',
        title:'Rock and Roll',
        artist:'Artist 1',
        rating:4,
        buy:'',
        price:"<a href='#' target='_blank' title='Download Sample'><i class='cloud download icon'></i></a> **<a href='test.php' name='buy1' target='_blank' title='Purchase'><i class='payment icon'></i></a>** <a href='#' target='_blank' title='View On Spotify'><i class='spotify icon'></i></a>  <a href='#' target='_blank' title='View On SoundCloud'><i class='soundcloud icon'></i></a> <a href='#' target='_blank' title='View On Itunes'><i class='apple icon'></i></a>",
```

Comment: The *only* way you can get data from the client's browser ("html") to the server ("php") is via some sort of HTTP request.  This is a *user-supplied* value that you want to submit to the server, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using forms or use AJAX to send a POST request. However, If you **really** don't want to use forms or use POST, GET, etc. a possibility is to take advantage of a PHP session.

Give this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/) a read, it'll hopefully get you started with PHP sessions.